# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Auth! : Ionic Cloud Services

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2

I set up Ionic Cloud Service and went through the initial process of authorizing a user.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Auth, User, UserDetails, IDetailedError} from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/signup/signup.html'
})
export class SignupPage {

  constructor(public auth: Auth, public user: User){
    let details: UserDetails = {'email': 'hi@ionic.io', 'password': 'puppies123'};

    this.auth.signup(details).then(() => {
      // `this.user` is now registered
    }, (err: IDetailedError<string[]>) => {
      for (let e of err.details) {
        if (e === 'conflict_email') {
          alert('Email already exists.');
        } else {
          // handle other errors
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

For some reason I am getting this error:ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Auth!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception

Everything is setup to a tee like the ionic cloud docs suggest : https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/#setup

I've looked everywhere for this answer

Comment: I've added an issue to github as well: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-issues/issues/219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the setup instructions it talks about how to add the ionic cloud NgModule to your module's imports:

https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

```
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I had missed these steps.  Making this change fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/signup/signup.html',
  providers: [Auth]
})
```

Not sure if it works because the ionic docs don't say anything about this, but it seems logical looking at your Error

Comment: If I try this I get "Cannot read property 'config' of undefined" as mentioned by Helder below.

Comment: Don't do this. The Ionic Cloud client needs to be specified as an "imported" NgModule in entirety, not case-by-case through providers. See our setup docs: http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

Comment: Please update your docs, as of Before getting started with Ionic Cloud, we expect you to be familiar with:' does not mean: 'in order for this framework to work like expected you must use:'

Answer (score 0):

Passing `Auth` in `providers`, starts to show that error in console:

```
Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```